# Lifecycle of an Entity Java Bean vs. Entity Object?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, entity, javabeans

I was under the impression that a Java Enterprise Entity had these life cycle states:

> New, Managed, Detached, Removed

But when reading up about Entity Java Beans, I came across the following states in the lifecycle of an Entity Java Bean:

> DoesNotExist, Pooled, Ready

I'm obviously confusing something about Entities vs. Entity Beans here, but I can't really find a clear explanation of what the difference between is? There must be a difference since they have different lifecycles... right?

Comment: The difference is quite huge. Entity Beans belong to EJB 2.1 spec, so they are EJBs at all. Entities are instead just annotated POJO and have a dedicated specification. If you read both specifications the differences are quite clear.